# Mysql fulltext search is not returning any rows which is having dot(.)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Here it is not fetching any rows from the table .

My table structure

*tb_business*

```
|  business_id  |    title    |
|-----------------------------|
|     1         |   abcd.efg  |
|     2         |   vwxyz     |
```

Here 'title' is the full text column.

query 1:

```
select * from  tb_business where MATCH(title) AGAINST("vwxy*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

result :

```
|  business_id  |    title    |
|-----------------------------|
|     2         |   vwxyz     |
```

Here everything is good.

query 2:

```
 select * from  tb_business where MATCH(title) AGAINST("abcd*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But here it is not fetching any rows. showing blank result. I expected the result like

```
|  business_id  |    title    |
|-----------------------------|
|     1         |   abcd.efg  |
```

I am using Mysql version 5.6.38

How do i solve this ?

Comment: How many rows in your table?  How many rows have 'abcd'?  Check out the 50% rule.

Comment: There are more than 2000 rows in the table and the word like 'abcd.' only 5 rows

Comment: MyISAM?  InnoDB?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ft%';`

Comment: I am using MyISAM.

Comment: Build a test case using InnoDB instead of MyISAM.